# How do you change the size of subplots created in Matplotlib plot/figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, figure

I am using subplots and matplotlib to create a figure shown below but I am having a lot of trouble changing the size of the individual plots (6). I can change the white "figure" easily but have not found in other online questions any way to change the individual plots sizes to make them larger (taller or increased height in my case) to be more readable. I am using this code and "fig" in my case is a figure.Figure variable. Thanks for any help!

```
wind_abs_anom = ((wind_abs.groupby('time.month') / wind_abs_clim))-1 #deviation from climo

sel = wind_abs_anom.sel(time=slice('2021-01', None))

left, *_, right = wind_abs_anom.longitude
top, *_, bottom = wind_abs_anom.latitude  # Min and max latitude.
extent = [left, right, bottom, top]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3,
                        figsize=(15, 7),
                        subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()},
                       )
#plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
#figure(figsize=(12,8),dpi=150)

for ax, (month, group) in zip(axs.flat, sel.groupby('time.month')):
    mean = group.mean(dim='time')
    im = ax.imshow(mean,
                   transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                   extent=extent,
                   cmap='RdBu_r', vmin=-3, vmax=3)
    ax.set_title(f'month = {month}')
    ax.coastlines()

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,
                    bottom=0.1, 
                    right=0.9, 
                    top=0.7, 
                    wspace=0.1, 
                    hspace=0.2)
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 15.5, forward=True)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.0, 0.6, 0.05])  # Left, bottom, width, height.
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax, extend='both', orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_label('Percent deviation')
    
plt.show()
```

My figure set using fig.set_size_inches(18.5,15.5)

[image]

Comment: These are geographic axes - the aspect ratio of the plots js set by the projection.  If you want to make them taller, you must make them wider as well.

Comment: thanks  - got it now - makes sense!